# Authorize.net linking issue in xcode 5.1.1 with SenTestingKit.Framework

Tags: ios, authorize.net

I have been working on the below issue since last 14 hours but unable to find out the solution.I have searched a lot but nothing worked out for me. Currently I am using the Xcode 5.1.1 and iOS SDK 7.1

I have following this [link](http://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/ios/) to integrate the Authorize.net SDK into my project. But getting these errors.I think this issue is related to SentestingKit.Framework.But unable to resolve this issue.Please let me know any suggestions or ideas.Thank you for reading my post.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to hack around with the collection of .h and .m files that Authorize.Net has included. These were the changes that I had to make to their SDK after I included their three folders into my project (put them into their own folder AuthNet):

- sdk/ANet SDK
- sdk/Headers
- sdk/Extension

  1. Project settings: 
     a. Set your Other Linker Flags with `-lxml2` to allow for xml parsing.
     b. Set your Header Search Paths with the path that contains "libxml2" header files. (ex. `/usr/include/libxml2` with recursive checked).
     c. Add `libxml2.dylib` in library list (like in this post: [iPhone libxml2 undefined symbols (with gdata, kissxml, touchxml, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033179/iphone-libxml2-undefined-symbols-with-gdata-kissxml-touchxml-etc))
  2. Search the folder for "test" in the filename and delete `authnetunittests.h` and `authnetunittests.m`
  3. Remove duplicate .m and .h that match filename `testAccount*.h` and `.m`
  4. If you already have Reachability in your project, delete the `Reachability.h` and `.m` that you just copied in with this sdk
  5. testaccountcaptcharesponse.h            comment out `@property NSString captchaView`
  6. messages.m          add `#pragma unused(statusMember)` x2
  7. transactionResponse.m           in init make `self.messages = [[Messages alloc] init];`
  8. LineItemType.m          in description function, change `NSMutableString` to `NSString`

And then this forum post is going to be helpful:
http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Problems-Registering-iOS-Device-for-Testing-in-Merchant-Account/m-p/45999/highlight/true#M23275